# Displaying REST data in JSP file

Tags: java, json, spring, jsp, rest

I am new to writing RESTFUL code in Java. [I have followed this tutorial that](http://www.journaldev.com/2552/spring-restful-web-service-example-with-json-jackson-and-client-program) explains how to write a RESTFUL program and return a JSON string. This question is a 2 part question.

1. Now i want to get the Employee name, and other details and display it on the JSP page. how can i do this ?
2. Now, i want to pass an ID and return the user object to the view, where i will display the details of that object in the JSP file. How can i do this ?

   ```
   @Controller
   public class EmployeeController {

   private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EmployeeController.class);

   //Map to store employees, ideally we should use database
   Map<Integer, Employee> empData = new HashMap<Integer, Employee>();

   @RequestMapping(value = EmpRestURIConstants.DUMMY_EMP, method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public @ResponseBody Employee getDummyEmployee() {
       logger.info("Start getDummyEmployee");
       Employee emp = new Employee();
       emp.setId(9999);
       emp.setName("Dummy");
       emp.setCreatedDate(new Date());
       empData.put(9999, emp);
       return emp;
   }

   @RequestMapping(value = EmpRestURIConstants.GET_EMP, method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public @ResponseBody Employee getEmployee(@PathVariable("id") int empId) {
       logger.info("Start getEmployee. ID="+empId);

       return empData.get(empId);
   }
   ```

Comment: Map<String, Object> obj= new HashMap<String, Object>(); put your list of objects in Map "obj" reference. In the jsp page, you can get the data like this,, ${obj.getNameOfEmployee}.

Comment: Can you show me a simple example ?